# Adding a new user manually in individual authorization mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5 (Code First), i'm trying  to add a new user in AspNetUsers table manually using SQL Management,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80EZ6.png)

when i want  to login with the new user it shows Invalid login attempt.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because the password of the user that you've manually added isn't *hashed*. You can add your users in the `Seed` method in your `Configuration.cs` and use the `ApplicationUser` class in Identity so it can do the *hashing* for the user password.

Here's an example on how to do it assuming you're using **Identity** in your ASP.NET MVC

```
protected override void Seed(Project.NameSpace.ApplicationDbContext context)
{

    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

    var user = new ApplicationUser 
    {
      UserName = "",
      FirstName = "",
      LastName = "",
      ...
    };

    userManager.Create(user, "ADD_PASSWORD_HERE"); // make sure that you follow the validation of your password here so you won't encounter any error. (Like password must have at least 1 number or special character and etc..)
}
```

Just add a validation if the UserName already exists in the database to avoid any error.

After doing this, just run your migration again and see if it works

Comment: could you more explain how to add users in the seed method cuz i still new in this area. thanks

Comment: Sure, but I'll get back to you. Still on my way home. Lol

Comment: @John I've updated my answer. See if it will work for you

Comment: i have followed your steps so that, the new user is uploaded in the AspNetUsers table with hashing pass, now when i try to login with the new user it shows Invalid login attempt.

Comment: Is the user password now hashed in your database?

Comment: There might be something wrong with how you authenticate user during login. Can you share that code as well?

Comment: perfect, its' working now. I should i add also the  UserName not  the email and the password only..that's helped m. many thanks

Comment: Congrats, happy coding!